# Help with Linked Server Error

Tags: sql-server

In SSMS 2008, I am trying to execute a stored procedure in a database on another server. The call looks something like the following:

```
EXEC [RemoteServer].Database.Schema.StoredProcedureName
   @param1,
   @param2
```

The linked server is set up correctly, and has both `RPC and RPC OUT` set to true. Security on the linked server is set to `Be made using the login's current security context`.

When I attempt to execute the stored procedure, I get the following error:

```
Msg 18483, Level 14, State 1, Line 1

    Could not connect to server 'RemoteServer' because '' is not defined as a remote login at the server. Verify that you have specified the correct login name.
```

I am connected to the local server using Windows Authentication. Anyone know why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe a kerberos double hop issue? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Be made using the login's current security context' translates as *impersonation* (aka. as 'self-mapping' in SQL Server linked in terms). Access a remote server under an impersonated context means *delegation*. So you need to set up the constraint delegation, see [Configuring Linked Servers for Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx):

> ### Requirements for the Client
>
> - The Windows user must have access permissions to SQLSERVER1 and
>     SQLSERVER2.
> - The user AD property **Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated** must not be
>     selected.
> - The client computer must be using TCP/IP or named pipes network connectivity.
>
> ### Requirements for the First/Middle Server (SQLSERVER1)
>
> - The server must have an SPN registered by the domain administrator.
> - The account under which SQL Server is running must be trusted for delegation.
> - The server must be using TCP/IP or named pipes network connectivity.
> - The linked server logins must be configured for self mapping.
>
> ### Requirements for the Second Server (SQLSERVER2)
>
> - If using TCP/IP network connectivity, the server must have an SPN registered by the domain administrator.
> - The server must be using TCP/IP or named pipes network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command, and it may fix it for you

```
exec sp_AddRemoteLogin 'YourServerName','LoginName'
```

I think (not sure) that the passwords have to be the same on both machines.